# UIBezierPath / Shape has strange positioning and sizing behaviour

Tags: swiftui, uibezierpath

I'm trying to convert some SVG data (some shapes for chinese characters) to an UIBezierPath. Each character consists of multiple UIBezierPath. This is an example for one UIBezierPath:

```
var mypath: UIBezierPath {
    let bp = UIBezierPath()
    bp.move(to: CGPoint(x: 147, y: 32))
    bp.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 203, y: 102), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 181, y: 74))
    bp.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 271, y: 189), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 242, y: 166))
    bp.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 274, y: 217), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 287, y: 204))
    bp.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 229, y: 235), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 258, y: 229))
    bp.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 193, y: 235), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 204, y: 241))
    bp.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 190, y: 219), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 183, y: 231))
    bp.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 143, y: 71), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 199, y: 195))
    bp.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 125, y: 33), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 134, y: 55))
    bp.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 147, y: 32), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 113, y: 5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 128, y: 9))
    bp.close()
    return bp
}
```

Since my final result consists of multiple UIBezierPaths I'm trying to scale them:

```
extension UIBezierPath {
    static func calculateBounds(paths: [UIBezierPath]) -> CGRect {
        let myPaths = UIBezierPath()
        for path in paths {
            myPaths.append(path)
        }
        return (myPaths.bounds)
    }
}

struct ShapeView: Shape {
    let bezier: UIBezierPath
    let pathBounds: CGRect

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let pointScale = (rect.width >= rect.height) ?
            max(pathBounds.height, pathBounds.width) :
            min(pathBounds.height, pathBounds.width)

        let pointTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1/pointScale, y: 1/pointScale)
        let path = Path(bezier.cgPath).applying(pointTransform)

        let multiplier = min(rect.width, rect.height)
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: multiplier, y: multiplier)
        return path.applying(transform)
        }
    }
```

View:

```
struct Drawer: View {

    let pathBounds = UIBezierPath.calculateBounds(paths: [mypath]) // to simplify I just add only one shape. Usually there are multiple

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            ShapeView(bezier: mypath, pathBounds: pathBounds) 
                .background(Color.red)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the result that is displayed:

[image]

As you can see: The shape is not centered and it's bigger than the screen. What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve that the shapes will be centered and fit perfectly in the entire screen?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what's that path transforming logic is about (if even you need it the defect is there), but just applying shape like

```
struct ShapeView: Shape {
    let bezier: UIBezierPath
    let pathBounds: CGRect

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            Path(bezier.cgPath)           // << simple conversion
        }
    }
```

gives this (probably what you did expect):

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it seems that there is a problem with the transformation logic. Your example works fine, but as mentioned I need to use multiple shapes like my example for one "final image" and need to scale them down so they fit in the screen.