# How to scale and arrange multiple UIBezierPath in one view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, uibezierpath

I have multiple `UIBezierPath`, let's say two squares:

```
var squareA: UIBezierPath {
    let bp = UIBezierPath()
    bp.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    bp.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0))
    bp.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
    bp.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100))
    return bp
}

var squareB: UIBezierPath {
    let bp = UIBezierPath()
    bp.move(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 200))
    bp.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 400, y: 200))
    bp.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 400, y: 300))
    bp.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300))
    return bp
}
```

Now I would like to display these two squares in one view. This view should be centered and scaled down when I set a specific frame size. Some thing like this:

```
MyUIBezierPathView(paths: [squareA, squareB])
    .frame(width: 200)
```

How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: I've tried some other solution guidelined by the link that @Aspari posted.

**Combine all shapes:**

```
extension UIBezierPath {
    static func calculateBounds(paths: [UIBezierPath]) -> CGRect {
        let myPaths = UIBezierPath()
        for path in paths {
            myPaths.append(path)
        }
        return (myPaths.bounds)
    }
}
```

**Now I'm calculating the new dimensions:**

```
struct ShapeView: Shape {
  
    let bezier: UIBezierPath
    let pathBounds: CGRect

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let scaleX = rect.width / pathBounds.width
        let scaleY = rect.height / pathBounds.height
        let scale = min(scaleX, scaleY)
        return Path(bezier.cgPath)//.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
    }
}
```

**And finally in my view I use this view:**

```
struct ShapeDrawer: View {
    let pathBounds = UIBezierPath.calculateBounds(paths: [squareA, squareB])

    ZStack{
        ShapeView(bezier: squareA, pathBounds: pathBounds)
        ShapeView(bezier: squareB, pathBounds: pathBounds)
    }
    .frame(width: 300, height: 300 * pathBounds.height / pathBounds.width)
    .background(Color.green)
}
```

and this works well! But it seems that this solution only works with "straight shapes" like squares, rectangles and so on. If I use some shapes with quadratic curves my shapes are not anymore in the center of the view. Here is an example:

Squares:
[image]

Curved Shapes:
[image]

Code for the curved shapes:

```
var han1: UIBezierPath {
    let shape = UIBezierPath()
    shape.move(to: CGPoint(x: 108, y: 552))
    shape.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 120, y: 447), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 118, y: 500))
    shape.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 153, y: 396), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 123, y: 413))
    shape.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 177, y: 407), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 168, y: 387))
    shape.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 157, y: 522), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 195, y: 467))
    shape.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 126, y: 564), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 144, y: 549))
    shape.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 113, y: 565), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 117, y: 568))
    shape.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 108, y: 552), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 107, y: 561))
    shape.close()
    return shape
}

var han2: UIBezierPath {

    let shape = UIBezierPath()
    shape.move(to: CGPoint(x: 288, y: 488))
    shape.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 292, y: 490), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 289, y: 489))
    shape.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 410, y: 579), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 371, y: 554))
    shape.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 421, y: 593), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 425, y: 583))
    shape.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 398, y: 621), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 415, y: 606))
    shape.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 362, y: 637), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 382, y: 636))
    shape.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 351, y: 620), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 349, y: 636))
    shape.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 347, y: 594), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 354, y: 608))
    shape.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 289, y: 513), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 326, y: 563))
    shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 288, y: 488), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 271, y: 489), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 262, y: 473))
    shape.close()
    return shape
}
```

I'm not sure, but it feels like the control points in the quadratic curves are taken into account and are the reason for this offset?

EDIT 2: It's not a problem with the form of shape, but it's a problem with the position of my paths in the view. If there is no shape in my view that starts at `CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)` which is the case for the curved shape, there will be this strange offset. How can I remove this?

EDIT 3: I've solved the problem. I had to change my view to:

```
struct ShapeView: Shape {
  
    let bezier: UIBezierPath
    let pathBounds: CGRect

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let scaleX = rect.width / pathBounds.width
        let scaleY = rect.height / pathBounds.height
        let scale = min(scaleX, scaleY)
        let path = Path(bezier.cgPath).applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -pathBounds.origin.x, y: -pathBounds.origin.y)) // <<<<<< this line 
        return path.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65770430/12299030?

Comment: The question is pretty close to my question, but I need to display multiple `UIBezierPath` in one view. The question you have posted is just about scaling  one `UIBezierPath`

Comment: @Asperi I've tried to solve my problem with your link. I think I'm on a good way... could you please check my newly added information?